# C++ 14 keywords under CentOS 6

Tags: makefile, centos6, qmake

I'm trying to compile a C++ project under different Linux OS's.  Under Fedora 27 all compiles great.  Under CentOS 6 it fails with

> error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

which I read means the wrong compiler is being used.  But, my qmake file contains:

```
CONFIG += C++14
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -no-pie
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie
```

On Fedora 27 the resultant Makefile contains:

```
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -Wall -g -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
```

On CentOS 6 the resultant Makefile contains:

```
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -Wall -g -std=gnu++0x -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
```

I concluded that the problem is CentOS 6 doesn't support nullptr (c++ 14), and gnu++0x is as recent as is available.

Is it possible to work around this problem?  Is there a compatibility include (for 'nullptr', 'override' keywords)?

I don't want to maintain seperate code bases for CentOS6 vs CentOS7.

Comment: [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) should be valid as of `c++11`.  What compiler version are you using on CentOS?

Comment: Compiler in CentOS 6 is "gcc 4.4.7 20120313".  I think the keywords nullptr and override are the only features I've taken advantage of in C++ 14.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp11) `nullptr` requires at least `gcc 4,6` and `override` requires `4.7`.

Comment: I found that too.  I'm wondering if there is a compatibility include file that will define the C++ 14 keywords to something compatible with C++11